# Adobe DTM - How Does Adobe provided code determine sCodeURL

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have the following Adobe provided code which is used in the "Customize Page Code section of the Adobe Analytics Tool set-up.

```
 function getAnalyticsAccount() {
    // Used to retrieve the satellite configuration report suite
    for (var toolid in _satellite.tools) {

        if (_satellite.tools[toolid].settings.engine == "sc") {
            console.log("---> toolid: " + toolid, _satellite.tools[toolid]);
            return _satellite.tools[toolid].settings.account;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is in a production environment, I'm getting a dev report suite returned which I believe is due to the sCodeURL pointing to the staging version of the satellite-Lib.js file. [image]

I'm not sure how DTM determines which version of the file to load. Does anyone know? Does anyone know more about this functionality?

Thanks,
MJ

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot you're in staging mode (note the console.logs are coming from a JS file ending in `-staging.js`). You either have DTM set the staging mode via the localstorage flag

```
localStorage.setItem('sdsat_stagingLibrary', true);
```

Or the embed code, which has `-staging.js` at the end, is included on the page.

The code you provided works fine for each environment... so once you're out of staging mode it'll return the prod RSID(s).

Comment: The above code was NOT produced in the dev. env, That is why I'm confused? The embedded code is the non-staging version (production) and I did NOT set any flags to point to staging.

Comment: And localStorage.getItem('sdsat_stagingLibrary'); returns null

Comment: Do you have the [DTM switcher plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-dtm-switch/nlgdemkdapolikbjimjajpmonpbpmipk?hl=en) enabled in Chrome perhaps?

Comment: I found out someone modified a bootstrap loader file and it was indeed loading the staging version of the DTM file. Sorry for the confusion!